# To change the images by using onclick function but it is not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqlnm.png)
I have used the above html code

[Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jXPP.png)
The above is the javascript code and onclick function is not working

Comment: You need to use `getElementsByClassName()` to access the elements with class name.. not with `getElementById()`

Comment: please replace those screenshots by the text they contain. please review [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the small images by the `id` attribute, but they have no id attribute. The `small-img` is a `class`.

Your JS code should look something like this:

```
var MainImag=document.getElementById('MainImg');
var SmallImg=document.getElementsByClassName('small-img');
```

Also you should consider using jQuery approach instead of binding the click event on every single one image:

```
$('.small-img').on('click', function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#MainImg').attr('src', src);
});
```